# CABasicAnimation performance before removeFromSuperView()

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation, removefromsuperview

I have a code-created button. Every time I click, I want it to perform CABasicAnimation before removeFromSuperView(). But if I add removeFromSuperView() after that, it will instantly removeFromSuperView() without any animation.

```
@objc func bubblePressed(_ bubble:Bubble){
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"opacity")
    animation.fromValue = 1
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2.0
    bubble.layer.add(animation, forKey:nil)
    bubble.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@objc func bubblePressed(_ bubble:Bubble){
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        // remove from super view
      bubble.removeFromSuperview()
    })
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"opacity")
    animation.fromValue = 1
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2.0
    bubble.layer.add(animation, forKey:nil)
    CATransaction.commit()

}
```

Workaround 2

```
     @objc func bubblePressed(_ bubble:Bubble){

                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"opacity")
                animation.fromValue = 1
                animation.toValue = 0
                animation.duration = 2.0
                animatio.delegate = self
                bubble.layer.add(animation, forKey:nil) 
            }

  extension ViewController: CAAnimationDelegate {

     func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation,  finished flag: Bool) {
        bubble.removeFromSuperview()

      // remove from super view in this function .. its Delegate method
                }
           }
```